# graphNEL to two columns table

Tags: r, graph

We can construct a graphNel object using ftM2graphNEL function from graph package. I want to know is there a function convert graphNel object to two columns matrix?

Comment: Can you clarify what the rows, and the 2 columns in the matrix represent? Do you mean there is a row for each edge, with first and second column being the start and end node of the edge?

Comment: if @WhiteViking is correct, then `edgeMatrix()`, discovered with `methods(class=class(graphNEL()))`

Comment: @MartinMorgan Actually the transpose: `t(edgeMatrix(...))` :-)

Comment: @WhiteViking, yes. Martin, thanks, it is exactly what I want! Thank you all!